# Regexp to match and capture unlimited repeating pattern

Tags: regex

I would need to match a parttern to the following examples

```
1
11
11-11
11-133-5
// any set of dash-delimited positive integers
```

and capture these in separate "groups" to reuse.

What would be the correct regexp? I was not successfull with https://regex101.com/r/laqMz8/1

Answer (score 0):

```
([0-9]+)((-*[0-9]+)*)
```

I simply added the Kleene star over the hyphen. :)